# How can I avoid warnings in Perl?

Tags: perl, warnings

I have a small piece of code for printing the contents in a text file like this,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (FILE, "2.txt") || die "$!\n";

my $var = <FILE>;
while ($var ne "")
{
    print "$var";
    $var = <FILE>;
}
```

Text file is,

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

After running the code i am getting a warning like this,

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
Use of uninitialized value $var in string ne at del.pl line 10, <FILE> line 3.
```

How to overcome this warning.

Comment: It would be nice if you use three args form of Open ie.,  `open(my $fh, '<', "input.txt") or die $!;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always use:

```
while(<FILE>) {
 print $_;
}
```

No such problems...

Comment: This can lead to bugs, as `while` does not localize `$_`

Comment: I have to admit that you are totally right. One need to be very careful when using this construct (i.e. nested while loops won't work correctly). I am aware of these problems and I will continue to use this coding style, but Perl newcomers should avoid it.

Answer (score 8):

The common idiom for reading from a file is this:

```
open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

while (defined(my $line = <$fh>)) {
    print $line, "\n";
}
```

Although the `while` loop implicitly tests for whether the result of the assignment is defined, it's better to do the test explicitly for clarity.

Comment: Note that `while` normally tests for truth, not defined-ness.  `while ($var = <FILE>)` is a special case where Perl adds an implicit `defined` test.

Comment: Please don't link to pirate copies of books

Answer (score 0):

The quickest fix is probably to replace

```
while ($var ne "")
```

with

```
while (defined $var)
```